# Rsync failing with Env Variable

Tags: rsync, env

I am using following script to rsync  back files. If I amy execute those one by one on shell it work. But when I use to execute theem in script it is giving error

"rsync: link_stat "/home/tan/testnfs#015" failed: No such file or directory (2)"

## 015 is no where in script, I have edited the script and verify that no blank space or character left. But have same problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
#========================================
#Environment varibale settings
#========================================
username=test
codedir=/home/tan/testnfs
nfs=10.100.200.4::test
adminemail=backup@tan.com
errorlog=/home/tan/backuperror_log.txt
dat=$(date)
rm -fr $errorlog
echo $dat 2>&1>> $errorlog
echo $nfsserver
echo ========== Before rsync =================
rsync --stats -vr --exclude "*.png" --exclude "*.jpg" --exclude "*.jpeg" --exclude "*.zip" --exclude "*.pdf" --exclude "*.doc" --exclude "*.csv" --exclude "*.swf" $codedir $nfs
if [ $? = 0 ] then
mail -s "$username sync--complete" $adminemail < $errorlog
else
mail -s "$username sync--Incomplete" $adminemail < $errorlog
fi
```

Comment: I had figure that out. I was editing script on windows and it was adding its line terminator. I have saved it as linux file with notepad++ and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had figure that out. I was editing script on windows and it was adding its line terminator. I have saved it as linux file with notepad++ and it worked